# Simple Rock Paper Scissors game, problems with returning score?

Tags: python

I'm writing this Rock Paper Scissors program for my Programming class, and having some problems getting the full score to show up at the end of the program. I'm super beginner in Python, so nothing too fancy here. For some reason, as I run the program, the only score that shows up is 1 regardless of how many times the game loops. What am I doing wrong here?

```
from myro import *
from random import *

def announceGame():
    """ Announces the game to the user """ 
    speak("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors. I look forward to playing you.") 

def computerMove():
    """ Determines a random choice for the computer """ 
randomNumber = random()
    if randomNumber == 1:
       compMove = "R"
    elif randomNumber == 2: 
       compMove = "P"
    else:
       compMove = "S"
return compMove 

def userMove():
    """ Asks the user to input their choice.""" 
    userChoice = raw_input("Please enter R, P, or S: ")
    return userChoice

def playGame(userChoice, compMove):
    """ Compares the user's choice to the computer's choice, and decides who wins.""" 

    global userWin
    global compWin
    global tie

    userWin = 0
    compWin = 0
    tie = 0

    if (userChoice == "R" and compMove == "S"):
       userWin = userWin + 1
       print "You win."

    elif (userChoice == "R" and compMove == "P"):
       compWin = compWin + 1
       print "I win."

    elif (userChoice == "S" and compMove == "R"):
       compWin = compWin + 1
       print "I win."

    elif (userChoice == "S" and compMove == "P"):
       userWin = userWin + 1
       print "You win"

    elif (userChoice == "P" and compMove == "S"):
       compWin = compWin + 1
       print "I win"

    elif (userChoice == "P" and compMove == "R"):
       userWin = userWin + 1
       print "You win"

    else:
       tie = tie + 1
       print "It's a tie"


    return compWin, userWin, tie


def printResults(compWin, userWin, tie):
    """ Prints the results at the end of the game. """
    print "     Rock Paper Scissors Results "
    print "------------------------------------" 
    print "Computer Wins: " + str(compWin)
    print "User Wins: " + str(userWin)
    print "Ties: " + str(tie) 

def main():
    announceGame()
    for game in range(1,6):
       u = userMove()
       c = computerMove()
       game = playGame(u,c)

    printResults(compWin, userWin, tie)  


main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside `playGame`, you set `userWin`, `compWin`, and `tie` to zero.  So every time you call that function, they get set to zero before the new values are added.  You should initialize these variables outside the function that you are calling in the loop.  (For instance, you could initialize them in `announceGame`.)

Comment: I did move that piece of code up to the announceGame() function, but it still comes up with 0 or tells me the local variable has been referenced before assignment?

Comment: You will still need to include the `global` statements in `playGame` if you want to reference the global variables from that function.  You just shouldn't set them to zero if you want to keep their values.

Comment: During your process of learning Python try to restructure your code and get rid of those `global` statements.